# Programming of abstracted remote systems

Tags: embedded, components, system, abstract

I'm trying to find terminology or article names that are relevant to the following general concept, so I can do some research on existing work:

1. Some remote system has a bunch of sensors or actuators. For example, a thermometer, accelerometer, death ray laser, etc. These are exposed to the outside world as abstracted generic components via some abstraction layer.
2. A local system can now ask the remote system what sort of components it has, and can also program the remote system to perform some sort of behavior. For example, the local system could send a process graph telling the remote system to read the temperature every 10 seconds and if the temperature is above 0, the system should fire its death ray laser at a random target.

The central part here is that there is some sort of functionality on the remote system that exposes its components as abstract parts, and the remote system also contains some sort of compiler or interpreter which allows our local system to send scripts, programming it what to do.

Comment: Not sure if there is a complete, ready to use, solution to this problem, but I would start here:  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Network_management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Network_management)

Comment: Questions that ask about where to find off-site resources are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow. Also, this is still a very broad question.

Comment: I'm not really asking about _where_ to find the resources. I'm just trying to find some relevant term that will help me find the resources for myself. I'll try to update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some terms from the industrial automation industry.  The sensors/actuators expose their interface via an electronic data sheet (EDS) or electronic design description (EDD) written in Electronic Design Description Language (EDDL).  A programmable logic controller (PLC), or just "controller", is used to program/control the system.  The PLC programming language could be ladder logic.  Check out [FDT Group](http://www.fdtgroup.org), which might give you some more terms and ideas to pursue.

Comment: Control system theory in general will be helpful.  What is an input, an output and a measurement and in what domains (temperature, position, etc).  Measurements generally give feedback to the control inputs to produce some output.